# How to achieve "Execute As User" in EF 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there a way to implement the `EXECUTE AS USER = 'xxx'` principle for security reasons within Entity Framework 4.0?

I tried the following:

```
public  class ImpersonateDatabaseEntities : DatabaseEntities
{
    private String _impersonateUser = null;

    public ImpersonateDatabaseEntities():base()
    {                   
       this._impersonateUser = "ProgUser";            
       base.Connection.StateChange += new System.Data.StateChangeEventHandler(Connection_StateChange);            
    }

    void Connection_StateChange(object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentState == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open &&
             e.OriginalState != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this.ExecuteStoreCommand("REVERT; EXECUTE AS USER = 'ProgUser';");
        }
    }
}
```

I alway get a an error on the SaveChanges() but I don't know how i can handle this problem.

Here is the error message i get:

```
Message: Failed to start a transaction on the provider connection. For more information, see the inner exception. 
Stacktrace: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A severe error occurred on the current command. Cancel any results
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
  at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
  ClientConnectionId:7aae526f-706f-4745-a3fd-2274f50be6ce

  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602409/execute-as-when-using-a-dbcontext-with-linq/11605161#11605161), but I don't get the answer out of it.

Comment: _see the inner exception_